# IPC::Shareable sharing

Tags: perl

I have a shared hash using the following:

```
my $glue = 'data';
my %options = (
    create    => 1,
    exclusive => 0,
    mode      => 0644,
    destroy   => 0,
);

tie %hash1, 'IPC::Shareable', $glue, { %options };
```

The %hash1 declared as above, is in a single perl file, but it is called by multiple applications, each application modifies its own index of the hash:

```
Application1 --> $hash1{app1}="alpha";
Application2 --> $hash1{app2}="betta";
...
```

given that applications may or may not run simultanously, will there be an data loss if application1 and application2 try to modify the hash simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a locking mechanism. (One is provided by the module.) Otherwise, changing any value of the hash can cause the loss of any other value changed at the same time. The following program demonstrates this quite easily:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IPC::Shareable qw( );

my $glue = 'data';
my %options = (
    create    => 1,
    exclusive => 0,
    mode      => 0644,
    destroy   => 0,
);

my ($key) = @ARGV
   or die("usage\n");

tie(my %h, 'IPC::Shareable', $glue, \%options);

my $c;
while (1) {
   $h{$key} = ++$c;

   my $got = $h{$key};
   die("$key was overwritten (got $got; expected $c)\n")
      if $got != $c;
}
```

Run it as follows in one console:

```
perl a.pl foo
```

Then run it as follows in another console:

```
perl a.pl bar
```

Comment: I made the following test.pl  `my $value = $ARGV[0];  
    my $i;
    while(1)  
    {  
        if ($handle_mem -> shlock())   
        {
            print "It is now locked for me\n";
            $memAAA{$value} = $i++;
            $handle_mem -> shunlock();
        } 
        else 
        {
            print "$i:The shared resource is locked\n";
        }    
    }`  

I had the file running in multiple instances with different ARGV values and I was not able to hit a single case of the "else" condition, is this correct and the system is just too fast? or am I missing something?

Comment: IPC::Shareable is good it has limits on shared memory segments / semaphore arrays. I tried to spawn 10 processes with a shared array (having 10,000 elements) and it exhausted the shm already. wish there was a workaround for that.

Answer (score 1):

The key (no pun intended) to make it work with [IPC::Shareable](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Shareable) it to provide a key as one of the initial parameters:

```
use IPC::SysV qw( ftok );
tie( %hash, 'IPC::Shareable', $glue, { key => ftok(__FILE__,1234567) });
```

It is better to use the `ftok` function from [IPC::SysV](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::SysV), because if you provide a string to IPC::Shareable, it will make it a numeric id using only the first 4 characters. Thus if you have two processes with one using `test_one` as a key and ther other `test_two`, both process will use the same shared memory segment, because in both case the resulting key produced by IPC::Shareable will be `1953719668`. Worse is that if the first process creates a shared memory segment of, say 2048 bytes and you want the second to create one of 524288 bytes, you will actually end up with accessing the first shared memory segment with only 2048 bytes in size and its data, with the risk of modifying the wrong data.

If you use `ftok` even if you spawn 10,000 processes, it will always access the shared data without loss, because IPC::Shareable uses [semaphore](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Semaphore) to ensure each process access the data one after the other.